# Хотелось бы услышать мнение людей знающих seo google

Tags: seo, интернет-магазин

Сейчас магазин с товара имеет не плохие позиции в гугл. Есть желание сменить структуру товаров.

**На данный момент структура товаров такая:**

- имя: Телефон Xiaomi Mi 8
- url: telefon-xiaomi-mi-8

*В карточке товара есть выбор модификаций, но они не имеют своих урл*

**Сменить на:**

- имя: Телефон Xiaomi Mi 8 64G Blue
- url: telefon-xiaomi-mi-8-64g-blue

Таким образом получится в разы больше страниц товаров.

Если сделать редиректы, например с Телефон Xiaomi Mi 8 на Телефон Xiaomi Mi 8 64G Blue ?

**Вопрос в том, какая будет просадка по гугл позициям, и как они обратно вернутся в индекс и на какие позиции?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ставить редирект и так даже будет лучше, когда у каждого торгового предложения свой урл.

301 редирект переносит, по моим скромным наблюдениям, 90-95% трафика, так что можно не беспокоиться. Гугл не даст пилить сук на котором сидишь.

А какие будут позиции, это нужно заваривать кофе и гадать на гуще)